# Razorpay payment screen not showing full screen in Tablet - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

**flutter - Razorpay payment screen not showing full screen while running in  android Tablet emulator** [Tablet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPO4.png) [Tablet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBhde.png)

Comment: bro i will give you suggestion you need to use singlechildScroll beacuse every screen size is differnt or second thing i assume you using static height and width thats causing problem.

Comment: bro I used singlechildScroll inside scaffold body I didn't prefer any height and width